# BeautifulSoup get text after html tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following `html` and I would like to get the text after `<b>Name in Thai</b>` which is `: this is what I want`

```
content = """
<html><body><b>Name of Bangkok Bus station:</b>
<span itemprop="name">Victory Monument</span>
<meta content="http://www.transitbangkok.com/stations/Bangkok%20Bus/Victory%20Monument" itemprop="url"/>
<meta content="http://www.transitbangkok.com/stations/Bangkok%20Bus/Victory%20Monument" itemprop="map"/>
<br/><b>Name in Thai</b>: this is what i want<br/>
</body></html>
"""
```

I tried the solution which is using `next_sibling` as follows

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
soup.find('b').next_sibling
```

However, I got `\n` as an output. Is there a way to get the text after particular tag (with explanation would be great!)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I got `\n` as an output.

That's because `find("b")` returns the first `<b>` tag it encounters and after the first one in your `content` there's only a newline.

If you instead iterate through all `<b>` tags. Then you'll see that `next_sibling` gives you what you want:

```
for tag in soup.find_all("b"):
    print(tag.text)
    print(tag.next_sibling)
```

Output:

```
Name of Bangkok Bus station:


Name in Thai
: this is what i want
```

You can iterate through them and find one that has something after by `strip()`'ing `next_sibling` from spaces.

```
for tag in soup.find_all("b"):
    after = tag.next_sibling.strip()
    if after:
        print(tag.next_sibling)
```